# How to start Service before BroadcastReceiver gets trigged in Android?

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` class which gets trigged sometimes And I also have a `Service` class. My `Service` class starts from my `Application` class named `G.class`. I want my `Service` class to start before `BroadcastReceiver` class. but as I see in `LogCat`, First `G.class` starts and it ends then `BroadcastReceiver` class starts and it ends then `Service` class starts. What is the problem?

**AlarmReceiver.class**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent;
import com.hadi.android.dm.app.Logger;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Logger.i("receiver started");
    //do something
}
```

}

**G.class**

```
import android.content.Intent;

public class G extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Logger.i("G started");
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ApplicationService.class));
    Logger.i("G ended");

}
```

**ApplicationService.class**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ApplicationService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Logger.i("service started");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Logger.i("service ended");
    }
}
```

**How my BroadcastReciever gets trigged**

```
public void schedule(long time) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
        android.app.AlarmManager alarmManager = (android.app.AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(android.app.AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(android.app.AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

**My LogCat**

```
07-09 00:44:00.797 18172-18172/com.hadi.android.dm I/MYAPP: G started
07-09 00:44:00.886 18172-18172/com.hadi.android.dm I/MYAPP: G ended
07-09 00:44:00.888 18172-18172/com.hadi.android.dm I/MYAPP: receiver started
07-09 00:44:00.890 18172-18172/com.hadi.android.dm I/MYAPP: service started
```

Comment: Where does your trigger come from for the broadcast receiver?

Comment: @tyczj the post edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this.  Here's what's happening:

- The alarm goes off
- The app, which is not running, is started.  The received broadcast is noted and an actuon to call the receiver put in the Handler on the main thread.
- The app creates the Application class.  This calls startService, which adds an action to create the service to the Handler on the main thread.
- The main thread message loop is returned to.  It takes the next message on the queue, the BR message, and runs it, starting the BroadcastReceiver.
- The main thread message loop is returned to.  It takes the next message on the queue, the SS message, and runs it, starting the Service.

There is no way to change the ordering in any of this.